# When can you take commodities out of the warehouse?

Tags: mundus-novus

In Mundus Novus, the [rulebook](http://www.redmeeple.com/site/images/Rules/Mundus_Novus_Rules(EN).PDF) says the warehouse allows you to store products in it at the end of the progress phase. The problem is it is not clear when you can take products out of it.

1. Can you take a commodity out of it in the trade step, or only in the progress step?
2. Can you swap the commodity found in a warehouse, replacing it with somewhing else in your hand? On what step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got pointed to [a thread at BGG with the author's answer to this question](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8049712#8049712). Cards stored in a warehouse are taken into its owner's hand in the beginning of his turn, at the same time he gets his 5 cards.

Comment: So I guess even in case of the pirate ship event, the player can chose to discard a card taken from a warehouse (that now is in his hand)?

Comment: Yes. You get the warehouse cards in the start of the supply phase. The Pirates event happen just after the supply phase.

Answer (score 2):

Play as if the cards are in your hand (besides the obvious new rule: you don't need to discard them).

So when can you use them? When you like. Replacing? Assume all the cards are you in your hand, so this question is now irrelevant. When? In the progress step.

Justifications:

> At the end of this phase, the players must discard all unused cards 
>   (unless they are placed in a warehouse).

Note it does not say the cards are put on top of the warehouse cards.

> Warehouses are valuable because they can 
>   store unused goods at the end of a round.

That's all warehouses do - there are no further clarifications on timing or anything else because there doesn't need to be any.

Practical:

In play, I tend to put the cards that can fit into my warehouses, on top of the warehouse cards - just because it permits me to play quicker, knowing that I've set aside the cards that I believe are important to keep and thus calculating the rest of my purchases can continue unencumbered. Understand that this convention is not in the rules, nowhere does it say you need to put your cards "on top" of the warehouse.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please point me to the reference that you used to write your answer?

Comment: As soon as I get home and look up the relevant rule(s).