# Fire and warehouses

Tags: mundus-novus

When there is a fire event, how exactly am I unable to use a warehouse? Am I unable to take commodities from it? I lose the commodities stored there? Or I simply can't add commodities to it, although I can take them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since cards may be stored in warehouses only in the end of a players turn (see [the rules](http://www.redmeeple.com/site/images/Rules/Mundus_Novus_Rules(EN).PDF), page 7 and 8) and [must be taken out of the warehouses when players get their 5 cards](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/18595/6518), the answer is straightforward: a player simply cannot store goods in them. This is explained by the game's author [in BGG](http://boardgamegeek.com/article/8049712#8049712).